# Adding Pear Package Extension to PHP-FPM

Tags: pear, php

So, I compiled php 5.2 for php-fpm along with the "--with-pear" option. How would I now include a pear package extension? Specifically, I want to add: http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime/download

Perhaps a really simple problem but I'm still really need to php-fpm and documentation is pretty limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like usual

```
$ /path/to/pear install Mail_Mime
```

or (if the pear script is already on your `PATH`)

```
$ pear install Mail_Mime
```

Comment: Ok. That installed it and restarted Nginx. But I don't think maybe there is a path issue because Drupal isn't picking up this extension. Where would I check the path?

Comment: Can I just add it as an extension to php.in file @ /usr/local/lib/php.ini ?

Comment: `Mail_Mime` is not a pecl extension, so no, you cant it add to `php.ini`. Is the `php_dir` (you can see its value with `$ pear config-show`) in your `include_path` (`$ php -i`, `phpinfo()`)?

Comment: $ php -i  // shows:
extension_dir => /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/ => /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/

Comment: Once more: `Mail_Mime` is _not_ a (pecl) extension!! So, whats about the `include_path`? Do you include the required files at all?